# Doubts about the slice category

Tags: category-theory

Given a Poset $(X, \leq)$ and $c \in X$, could you illustrate how to see that the slice category $c/X$ is $[c,\rightarrow]$. I understand that I can identify every object $f: c \rightarrow x$ there with x, but I can't see how to identify the morphisms and their composition with the structure of $[c, \rightarrow]$.

**Edit:** In general, what is the intuitive notion of slice category $c/C$ of $C$ under $c$?

Comment: What is the definition of $[c,\rightarrow]$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber It is the **up set** of $x$ endowed with the order relation of $X$ restricted to $[c, \rightarrow]$

Answer (score 3):

The slice category has objects the morphisms $f:c\to x$ and morphisms $g\to f$ commutative diagrams $c\to_g y \to_f x.$ Translating this into the poset language, an object $f$ is just an object $x$ of $X$ with $c\le x$ and a morphism is a relation $c\le y\le x.$ So the slice category $c/X$ is just the set of elements of $X$ which are larger than $c.$

Comment: In general, What is the intuitive notion of slice category $c/C$?

Answer (score 3):

In a posetal category morphisms are unique in the sense that $\hom_X(a,b)$ is a singleton set if $a\le b$ and empty otherwise. Therefore the compositions are also the unique possible maps.

Specifically, the arrow $c\to x$ as object of $c/X$ corresponds to $x\in [c,\to]=\{x\in X:c\le x\}$, and the (necessarily commutative) triangle $c\to x\to y,\ c\to y$ as morphism in $c/X$ corresponds the unique arrow $x\to y$ in the posetal category of $[c,\to]$ which exists because $x\le y$ (because there's an arrow $x\to y$ in the posetal category of $X$).

Comment: In general, What is the intuitive notion of slice category $c/C$?

Comment: For example the category of pointed sets (sets with a single constant operation and homomorphisms) is the slice category $1/Set$ where $1$ is a singleton set.